# How to print output of multiple threads in separate windows?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on a code where i get input from different sensors using Raspberry Pi. Is there any way I can get outputs in different console windows.

The code is something along these lines.

```
def usensor():
    distance1=GPIO.input(port1)
    print("Distance Left: %s" %distance1)
    distance=GPIO.input(port)
    print("Distance Right: %s" %distance)

def lsensor():
    distance=Linput();                          #predefined function
    print("Forward Distance: %s" %distance)

def main():
    a = threading.Thread(target=usensor)
    s = threading.Thread(target=lsensor)
    a.start()
    s.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I show the outputs of the two threads in separate windows so its easier to read?

Comment: 2 Ideas: 1) Split the code into two scripts or one module and two "ui" scripts and then run with `tmux` or 2) use the `curses` module for advanced terminal output

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: A dirty way to achieve this is spliting your script into 2 and use `subprocess` module https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html

Comment: You could also write to 2 files and `tail -f` them.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into programming windows (which is perfectly practical in Python but probably a complexity you can do without), I'd suggest being sneak and using a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).

Suppose you create a named pipe (they're often referred to as FIFOs) called `/tmp/pipe1`. You can have your program open this FIFO for output and write one of the output streams to this (investigate the `file` argument of the `print` function).

All you would need to do then is open another terminal window, and run the command

```
cat /tmp/pipe1
```

As your program writes to the named pipe, the output should appear in this second window. Voila!